# postgresql query - find max timestamp for each month

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to retrieve the record which contains the max timestamp each month of the year.

For this, I created a temporary table (date_series) with every month from January 2016 till today. I want to find the maximum timestamp for each id for each month of the year and show the corresponding id and status.

This is what I have so far:
The `createddate` field is

```
with date_series as(
    SELECT * FROM generate_series('2016-01-01'::date,
                              now(), '1 month')
)
select max(a.created_at), a.id, d.generate_series, a.status
from sales a, date_series d
group by 2,3,4
```

However I am not sure how to structure the query logically to reach these results.

Comment: I'm thinking I need to add an additional subquery to find the `max(a.created_at)` dates and then join that with the temporary date table.

Answer (score 1):

Read about **DISTINCT ON** http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-select-distinct/

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(a.id, a.status, date_trunc('month',cdate))
       a.id,
       a.status,
       date_trunc('month',cdate) "Month",
       a.created_at
FROM sales a
ORDER BY a.id, a.status, date_trunc('month',cdate), created_at DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have gaps in your month (or don't care), and the timestamps are truly unique, this should work:

```
with salez as (
  select
    id, status, created_at,
    max (created_at) over (partition by date_trunc ('month', created_at)) as max_date
  from
    sales
)
select
  max_date, id, date_trunc ('month', created_at)::date, status
from salez
where
  max_date = created_at
```

The risk with `max` is that if you can have two records with the exact same timestamp, this will give you two records of output for that month.  If that is possible and will break your query, use `row_number` instead:

```
with salez as (
  select
    id, status, created_at,
    row_number() over (partition by date_trunc ('month', created_at
      order by id desc)) as rn
  from
    sales
)
select
  created_at, id, date_trunc ('month', created_at)::date, status
from salez
where
  rn = 1
```

Comment: Your `order by id desc` will not necessarily assign row_number 1 to the maximum timestamp row per partition, as OP requested. I suggest to use sth like `row_number() over (partition by date_trunc('month', created_at) order by created_at desc) as rn`.